# Google App Engine - Does receiving mail (with attachments) bill Incoming Bandwidth?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

Does receiving mail (with attachments) in Google App Engine bill Incoming Bandwidth?

Is the answer is yes -
Is there a way to reject an email after fetching its headers only, and not be billed on its attachment (in order to reduce incoming bandwidth)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I have an application that all it does is receiving emails and storing them (about 20-30MB of emails+attachments per day) the incoming bandwidth remains at zero, so it seems that emails are not measured in the incoming bandwidth quota.